# Why won't my variable change within my method?

Tags: java, loops, methods

I am making a farenheit to celsius conversion table for farenheit temperatures between 0 and 20 using a loop, and I am having trouble getting my method to return the proper celsius. So far, the program will output the proper farenheit temperatures through 20, but it will output the celsius conversion for 0* farenheit for every farenheit output. How can I get my method to use the increasing farenheit variable in the method's equations?
Here is my code thus far:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class CelsiusTemperatureTable
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");

      double farenheit = 0;
      double celsius = celsius(farenheit);


      while (farenheit <= 20)
      {

         System.out.println( farenheit + "\t\t" + df.format(celsius));

         farenheit++;
      }
   }

   public static double celsius(double farenheit)
   {
      double temperature = farenheit - 32;
      double temperature1 = temperature * .556;
      return temperature1;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method  `celsius(farenheit)` is called only once, 
after that you do a loop, increasing the farenheit but no calling the method again...

you have to move the  `double celsius = celsius(farenheit);` inside the while loop